# Textbook suggestions for rigorous fluid dynamics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, textbook-recommendation, fluid-dynamics

I am interested in studying fluid dynamics and am searching for a good introductory textbook. I know just the very basics of fluids on the physics side. For mathematical prerequisites, I have completed a course on integration theory, and have a basic understanding of functional analysis and PDE, though by no means am I an expert.

I have done some searching online and most of the books I have come across lean more towards physics, numerical methods, and/or mathematical modeling. What I am instead looking for is something that is more mathematical and analysis/PDE oriented (and ideally one that does not assume too much of this material and introduces it as necessary), targeted towards early graduate students in mathematics. A good example of what I would like are Professor Tao's [lecture notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/category/teaching/254a-incompressible-fluid-equations/).

Are there any textbooks in this direction?

Comment: The 2d-case has already many established mathematical results and often serve as a toy/test case. A nice book is https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Two-Dimensional-Turbulence-Cambridge-Tracts/dp/1107022827 "Mathematics of Two-Dimensional Turbulence" by S.Kuksin and A.Shirikyan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- JC Robinson, JL Rodrigo, & W Sadowski (2016) Classical theory of the three-dimensional Navier-Stokes equations.
- OA Ladyzhenskaya (1963) The mathematical theory of viscous incompressible flow.

Comment: That first book seems to be exactly what I need, thank you! If you have happened to have read through it before, how is it? Is it well suited for self-study and with only a minimal background in PDE?

Comment: I haven't read all of it but the bits I read it seemed well suited to self-study and didn't require too much knowledge of PDE theory.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try then.

Comment: No problem, would you mind accepting my answer if you believe this answers your question?

Comment: Of course, sorry about not doing so earlier.

Answer (score 5):

An older, classic text is [Mathematical Theory of Compressible Fluid Flow](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486439410) by Richard von Mises.

More recent text books include

- [Introduction to Mathematical Fluid Dynamics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486615545) by R.E. Meyer.
- [An Introduction to Theoretical Fluid Dynamics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461269342) by S. Childress.
- [A Mathematical Introduction to Fluid Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387979182) by A.J. Chorin and J.E. Marsden.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. These all seem like wonderful books, but I am looking for something more on the PDE side. For example, existence, uniqueness, use of Sobolev spaces, weak solutions...etc.

Answer (score 4):

Constantin, Foias, *Navier-Stokes Equations* (1988).

This classic is not a textbook exactly, but gives a lot of detail and should be pretty readable.